# SQL validation in IntelliJ IDEA: How to turn it off?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Does anyone know how I turn off the SQL validation in Intellij IDEA 9?

We often have more than one connection to a different type of database within one class. IntelliJ only allows one SQL dialect per class, resulting in what IntelliJ thinks are errors, so litters my code with red lines.

Ideally I'd just like to turn the errors off completely, as they are distracting and not actually real errors.

Answer (score 13):

Settings > Inspections. Unselect 'SQL'. Alternatively you can place your cursor on the error and press alt+enter. One of the options will be 'Disable Inspection'.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work if intellij marks the error as 1 single character, since the cursor can then only be put next to it rather than inside it

Answer (score 9):

You could use a comment *language=* before the statement, i.E.

```
//language=MySQL
String stmt1 = "INSERT INTO a (b) values(?)";
//language=Oracle
String stmt2 = "SELECT SYSDATE FROM dual";
```

See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-language-injections.html

Answer (score 4):

You can alternatively turn off the specific inspection that is bothering you. No need to turn off all SQL support (e.g. auto-complete hints are nice).

To do this, you can go to Settings --> Editor --> Inspections --> SQL and uncheck the ones you don't want. For instance, I just disabled "No data sources configured" and "Unresolved reference".

In IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.2, this looks like this:

[image: IntelliJ SQL Inspections]

Answer (score 1):

for IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3 you can disable sql inspections:
File | Settings | Inspections | SQL

[image]

[image: turn off sql inspections]

Answer (score 0):

Usually I just put my cursor to the right of the error so the lightbulb appears. Them press alt-enter and then arrow-right. Another menu pops up that provides various supression options.

I'm not totally sure this will let you supress all the warnings globally, but you usually get rid of the ones that are troubling you fairly quickly.

Comment: Unfortunately that just jumps me to the dialog box to change SQL dialect for that class. Same issue! More than one dialect per class :(

Answer (score 0):

No longer exists in 2018.2 Community Edition. No SQL under "Inspection" part.

Found a ticket here:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206751355-Database-navigator-plugin-generates-errors

Seems no solution yet. I am with DB navigator 3.1.